# Why would Web3 return an empty array after calling the solidity function

Tags: solidity, remix, web3.py, python

So I want to interact with my Smart Contract from remix with python library called Web3.
The problem is when I try to call the function from the smart contract it runs successfully but it only returns an empty array instead of the actual data.

Solidity Code:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract MyContract {
    Evidence[] public evidence;

    struct Evidence {
        string name;
        string location;
    }
    
    function addPerson(string memory name, string memory location) public {
        evidence.push(Evidence(name, location));
    }
}
```

Python Code:

```
import json
from web3 import Web3

url = 'HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545'
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(url))

web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0]

abi = json.loads('my json')
bytecode = "my bytecode"


status = web3.isConnected()

if status == True:
    print("Connected")
    MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi = abi, bytecode = bytecode)
    transaction = MyContract.constructor().transact()
    receipt = web3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(transaction)
    contract = web3.eth.contract(
        address = receipt.contractAddress,
        abi = abi
    )
    tx_hash = contract.functions.addPerson("Adam", "Near House").call()
    print(tx_hash)

else:
    print("Not Connected")
```

Comment: Can you show me the code where you're trying to get the `evidence` field?

Comment: i am also experiencing this. did you understand what was happening?